# Multiples values in yAxes with same xAxes

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I would like to make a graph like the imagen, that is, with the same "x" values multiples "y" values.
I use ng2-charts library, and I have tried this:

this.chartType = 'line';
this.chartLabels = ['21 Enero', '23 Enero', '24 Enero', '25 Enero', '26 Enero', '27 Enero', '3 Feb', '6 Feb'];
this.chartOptions = {
responsive: true,
showLine: false,

```
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    autoSkip: false, 
                }

            }],
            yAxes: [{ 
                beginAtZero: true,
            }] 
        }
    };
    this.chartData = [{
        data: [65, 90, 80, 85, 90, 87, 91, 98],
        label: "1ª Toma",
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 1,
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        fill: false
    },
    {
        data: [59, 95, 81, 82, 97, 100, 99, 88],
        label: "2ª Toma",
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 1,
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        lineTension: 0,
        fill: false 
    },
    {
        data: [80, 101, 95, 97, 90, null, null, null,],
        label: "3ª Toma",
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 1,
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        lineTension: 0,
        fill: false 
    }
    ];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2GKE.png)

Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible if you use the declare your datapoints as objects so you can tell which X and which Y it has to use

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Sales", "Revenue", "Profit", "Loss"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: 'Sales',
        y: 20
      }, {
        x: 'Revenue',
        y: 10
      }, {
        x: 'Revenue',
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: 'Revenue',
        y: 50
      }, {
        x: 'Profit',
        y: 20
      }, {
        x: 'Loss',
        y: 10
      }, {
        x: 'Loss',
        y: 20
      }],
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'red',
      lineTension: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```